# Extracting @IBOutlets properties values out of the main view controller

Tags: swift, subclassing

Since the beginning I've been working with the MVP model in order to keep things going but now, months later, I realize that most of my projects have "Massive View Controllers". Extensions worked well at first to unclutter the actual view controller file but technically the code is still in the view controller.

A more practical approach to my question is in my last project were I have an In-App purchase after which the user gets some new features unlocked. We are supposing that the entire StoreKit logic is doing its job, the purchase was successfully finished and you are just about to give the new functionality to the user.

In order to handle this I have a function `func unlockFeatures` inside the main view controller (`PreferencesViewController`) that is triggered by and observer when the In-App-Purchase is successfully made.

```
class PreferencesViewController: UIViewController {

    ...
    @obc func unlockFeatures {
        InAppPuchaseButton.isEnabled = false
        InAppPuchaseButton.applyOpacity(opacity: 1.0)
    }
    ...
}
```

At this point, when I only had to enable and change the opacity of one single button everything seems clean. My question is how to handle situations when inside the `func unlockFeatures` you need to handle multiple lines of UI code like this:

```
class PreferencesViewController: UIViewController {

    ...
    @obc func unlockFeatures {
        InAppPuchaseButton.isEnabled = false
        InAppPuchaseButton.applyOpacity(opacity: 1.0)
        InAppPuchaseButton.isHidden = false
        RefreshLabel.text = "DOWNLOADING EVENTS"
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        //And keep going for 50 lines more of code!!
    }
    ...
}
```

To me it looks cluttered and I would like to extract this function outside the `PreferencesViewController` and call it just when I need it. Is there a way to extract all this UI logic outside the view controller class or this is a bad practice?

Comment: Hi @BES!  Since you're new on StackOverflow, please be aware that some senior community members might downvote and request edits to your question because it's too broad. I suggest you specify a solvable problem (i.e. more details on the runtime error) and look for architecture suggestion in existing posts; anyway, I suggest khanlou.com, the topic of "coordinators", and Uncle Bob's "Architecture: The Lost Years" for high-level input. TL;DR: extract service objects from your code and put app logic in there.

Comment: Hi @ctietze! Right now I'm going to edit my question in order to go more in depth about what I mean. Btw the error I get is "(lldb)". Thanks for your answer.

Comment: See my revised answer responding to your edits.

Comment: When you see `(lldb)` in the Xcode console, that's the command prompt where you can enter LLDB commands like `po self` to print an object description and the like. The actual error is either printed before, or if it isn't, it's a generic runtime exception that Xcode shows with a red ribbon in the source code with an "EXC_something` error code to the right.

Comment: @matt Your revision done after my question update was the clarification I was looking for. I wasn't aware  that having the UI inside the view controller class is the good practice. Thanks

Comment: Another way to solve this would be to put all the functionality that comes to life after the user purchases in its own view controller. That way, if the user tries to get there without purchasing, there is just _one_ gateway that says it's not possible — we don't let the user go to that view controller at all. And inversely, if the user has purchases, that entire next view controller springs to life and the user can do everything in it.

Comment: That's a great idea too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The in-app purchases example is an excellent one. What we'd like to do here is provide a single centralized object that can (for example):

- Act as the locus for IAP-related code that doesn't involve the interface, such as acting as the SKPaymentTransactionObserver
- Act as a gateway for the rest of the app to be able to ask whether the user has made a purchase (of course our object will know the answer by consulting user defaults, but that will be an implementation detail hidden by its public API)

It makes sense to break these functionalities off from the view controller, because they have nothing to do with *controlling any views*.

So this is a perfect opportunity to use a *helper class*. A typical implementation would be a class that dispenses a singleton instance, which we obtain and store in a property of the app delegate or of the root view controller, either of which is persistent and easily reached from anywhere in the app.

---

In a broader context, I use this sort of helper object all the time, to tackle exactly the sort of issue you describe. For example, in a game app, I had a *lot* of code in the main view controller until I broke off several areas of operation into helper classes, because they really had nothing to do with the *control of the views*. For example, the logic of the timer and maintenance of the score went off into a helper object. The "state machine" that decides what to do next when we come to the next stage of the game went off into a helper object. And so on.

---

In your revised question, you say:

> To me it looks cluttered and I would like to extract this function outside the PreferencesViewController and call it just when I need it. Is there a way to extract all this UI logic outside the view controller class or this is a bad practice?

There is nothing "cluttered" here; it's all in one function, which is right. The good practice is to have the UI manipulation *inside* the view controller class but possibly *call* it from elsewhere (e.g. by the helper I described in my answer). Actually what *I* would do is have the helper post a notification so that it is agnostic about what will happen; it just shouts "Okay, the user purchased!" and the view controller receives the notification and calls that method.

Comment: You'll notice that I speak here of a helper _class_ rather than a _struct_. Ideally I'd prefer a struct, but in many cases, where we need Objective-C to talk to us or we're going to be doing a lot of mutation, a struct is too much trouble.

Comment: Sure, I already have the entire Store logic working fine and saving inside a static variable wether or not the purchase has been made. My concern is just after this point in time when you have to deliver the new functionality to the user. Providing this new features could be, for example, enabling a UIButton on the UI that was disabled before the In-App-Purchase was made. How do you subclass the actual `UIButton.isEnabled = true`?

Comment: I don't know what "subclass" has to do with anything. There are no subclasses in this story. Nor do I see what your question is. It's not the job of the helper to enable anything; that's the job of the view controller. It's the job of the helper to signal that the user has purchased at the moment that it occurs, and to report on demand that the user has purchased.

Comment: You are right @matt I see what the helpers job is, and it's working fine in my app. What I don't see is how to handle cases when the "enabling job", that has to be done by the view controller, has over 50 lines of code. Is there a way to subclass that in order to remove those 50 lines from the view controller?

Comment: You keep using the word "subclass". I don't think it means what you think it does.

Comment: Maybe is that! Let's see, isn't `PreferencesViewControllerVisuals` a subclass from `PreferencesViewController` by doing that? `class PreferencesViewControllerVisuals: PreferencesViewController {`

Comment: Yes, but I don't see what that has to do with the question you asked. You asked how to make your view controller less massive, and I suggested putting some functionality into helper objects. The use of a helper object is not about subclassing anything.

Comment: In other words you're telling me that all the visual changes, like enabling/disabling buttons after an In-App-Purchase is made, they have to be always on the view controller no matter what. Is that right?

Comment: No, I'm not telling you that anything _has_ to be anywhere. But the view controller's chief job is to _control views_. It would be very bad practice to let any other object touch the view controller's view or any subview of it. The sole exception is that you might subclass a UIView subclass in order to let that view somehow configure itself; but in this use case, that would seem to be unnecessary and a pointless complication. You asked for advice about best practices and that is what I gave you.

Comment: To me, it seems @BES asks for a subclass because he wonders why this takes so much code, as if he missed something built-in he could call, like all the stuff that comes for free in the `UIViewController` parent class. When you subclass, you do get the parent class's stuff for free without calling anything, but `UIViewControllers` don't help you with IAP like that. There's no convenient built-in functionality that I know about (which doesn't say much) you could call from your code, either. So this truly is up to you to write, even if it looks oddly much.

Comment: That's right @ctietze, I was worried for the amount of code those simple UI lines were taking but I understand what you mean with your input. Thanks